# Mac OS - Lock a file with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to lock a file on Mac by way of Node.js.

[image]

The `npm` modules I've been looking at, such as `lockfile`, and `proper-lockfile`, don't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Is this possible with Node.js?

---

*Update*
Is this something I should simply be handling with `chmod` operations in Node? I figured there could be a shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal command to lock a file is `chflags uchg <filename>` whilst to unlock it is `chflags nouchg <filename>`.

You can use `exec` to simply call the command:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec(`chflags uchg tempfile`, (err, stdout, strerr) => {
  console.log(stdout, strerr);
});
```